# Java Dictionary - Assign int values to strings

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency, performance

Sorry if this seems like a simple question, but I need to store 60 million records, which contain a total of 2 million distinct strings. In the 60 million records, I want to store an integer representation of the string, so as I am loading the records, I will assign an integer to them

e.g. 
if my input is a,b,c,a
then I will store 1,2,3,1

Records will be read and submitted in multiple threads. I have come up with the following, from a threading an efficiency perspective, are there any improvements that I can make?

edit: I will be building maps that have up to 2 million keys. If I don't do this I will have to use Strings. I am using TIntHashMap from Trove with the below approach and I'm getting much better performance

Many thanks,

```
private final Map<String, Integer> stringDictionary = new HashMap<>(2000000);

private int index = 0;

private final ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public int getStringCodeIntegerValue(String stringCode) {
    readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
    Integer result = stringDictionary.get(stringCode);
    if (result == null) {
        // Must release read lock before acquiring write lock
        readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
        readWriteLock.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            result = stringDictionary.get(stringCode);
            if (result == null) {
                stringDictionary.put(stringCode, ++index);
                result = stringDictionary.get(stringCode);
            }
            // Downgrade by acquiring read lock before releasing write lock
            readWriteLock.readLock().lock();
        } finally {
            readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock(); // Unlock write, still hold read
        }
    }
    readWriteLock.readLock().unlock();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: why do you want an integer instead of string? How will you use stored data? (Do you need fast reads/writes/searches etc?)

Comment: @aviad Hi, I will need to build many combinations of arrays from the records, they will have a length of up to 5 million. Using integer is driven from a memory optimisation perspective. I would say the average length of string I have is about 30 characters

Answer (score 0):

First, it sounds as though you're trying to reinvent interned strings? Is there any reason why you can't use the interned strings provided as standard for your problem?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--

Second, if you really do need to do this yourself, rather than layering your own locking strategy on top of `HashMap`, you're probably better off using [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), which provides support for multiple concurrent writers.

In answer to your question in the comments, here's a stab at implementing `getStringCodeIntegerValue` (untested, but I'm reasonably confident that it's right - the functionality of `putIfAbsent` is almost exactly what you want):

```
final AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> stringDictionary = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

public int getStringCodeIntegerValue(String stringCode) {
    Integer result = stringDictionary.get(stringCode);
    if (result != null)
        return result;
    else
        return stringDictionary.putIfAbsent(stringCode, index.incrementAndGet());
}
```

This implementation might result in an index value being "discarded" if two threads both try to add the same string simultaneously, but I don't believe that that should be a problem for you.

Having said all of this, if you've tested your implementation against the standard map, and it's performing better, that suggests that concurrent updates of `stringDictionary` aren't an issue for your particular usage patterns, so perhaps you should just stick with what you've got?

Having said *that*, it stills sounds to me as though you're trying to reinvent interned strings. Why can't you use interned strings—they sound like exactly what you need to me?

Comment: thanks. see my edit regarding using primitive maps instead of java's own ones. Also, if I use ConcurrentHashMap how do I handle the case where the value doesn't exist, so I need to increment the counter, insert the new value and return it?

Comment: I notice that you've asked 5 questions on SO and accepted only a single answer. You will increase your chances of receiving answers to future questions if you accept answers (or indicate why they are not acceptable).

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment I am still not clear what are you trying to achieve.

However, you can produce an integer digest of string (the string can be of any length). For example SHA1 or MD5. You can use Apache Commons [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha%28java.lang.String%29) for that.

Then you can store for each string the digest and the physical string, but having SHA1/MD5 column will help you to index the data by digest and access the records faster.

Keep in mind that the digest is irreversible i.e you can not reproduce the original string out of digest.

Hope it helps!